# django Count on FK with Sum and filters

Tags: django, django-orm

I have to find the number of participants where the sum of two fields is above a given field. Following models:

```
class Examination(models.Model):
    total_score = models.FloatField(_('Total score'), blank=False, null=False, default=60)

class ExamParticipation(models.Model):
    examination = models.ForeignKey(Examination, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='examination_participations')
    total_score = models.DecimalField(_('examination score'), max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default=0)
    additional_score = models.DecimalField(_('additional score'), max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default=0)
```

So for a given Examination I have to count how many participants, where the sum of total_score and additional_core, have more or equal like total_score/2. Is this feasible with a queryset at all or do I have to loop over the results?

I tried following query:

```
    def count_sufficient_participations(self):
        qs = self.values('examination_participations').order_by('examination_participations').annotate(
        ts=Sum(F('examination_participations__total_score') + F('examination_participations__additional_score'))
    ).annotate(cnt_suff=Count('examination_participations')).filter(ts__gte=30)
```

but does not seem to work and I do not know how to replace 30 with the field total_score from examination. I want to have something like examination.cnt_suff for my template. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found that 30 can be replaced with F('total_score') / 2

Answer (score 1):

`Sum` is a `aggregate` function which means keeps in process all values for a column in match with query.

But you would like to sum current row's 2 column.

So use

```
ts = F('examination_participations__total_score') + F('examination_participations__additional_score')
```

instead of

```
ts = Sum(F('examination_participations__total_score') + F('examination_participations__additional_score'))
```

Comment: ok this is correct, but this still gives me the count per row. I need the count over the whole queryset.

Comment: @cwhisperer if you need only count use `...filter(ts_gte=30).count()` and remove `.annotate(cnt_suff=Count('examination_participations'))`

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution:

```
def count_sufficient_participations(self):
    qs = self.annotate(
        cnt_suff=Count('examination_participations', filter=Q(total_score__lte=(F('examination_participations__total_score') + F('examination_participations__additional_score')) * 2))
    )
    return qs
```

Thanks for your help.